# Why can't I replace a variable with a constant in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, math

Here is a very simple C/C++ code that surprised me because it does not give the same result.

```
float f = -123.123f;
unsigned u1 = -123.123f;
unsigned u2 = f;
printf("%d %d\n", u1, u2); // 0 -123
printf("%u %u\n", u1, u2); // 0 4294967173
```

The output gives:

```
0 -123
0 4294967173
```

Why won't the result be the same?

This is worrying because symbols with same meaning cannot be substituted in the language.

I tested the example with C++ compiler on programiz.com website.

I expected that the results are same.

Thank you for the answers, let us forget the printing part. Understood, it is undefined so the values may be different individually.

Comment: *This is worrying...* -- Are you saying that you are actually going to write code like this?

Comment: Note: The program has undefined behavior since you use `%d` for `unsigned` variables I think the result when using the correct conversion specifier will surprise you even more.

Comment: FYI, you are converting from floating point to integer.  This involves truncation.

Comment: Because integer variables aren't floating point variables.

Comment: The `unsigned int` doesn't handle negative numbers, because of the term *unsigned*.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick one.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That doesn't explain why the conversion is different depending on whether the source is a float variable versus a float literal.

Comment: Try this:  `unsigned int number = -5; std::cout << number << "\n";`  Turn your compiler errors and warnings to maximum.

Comment: When I compile the code I get the following warning for the `u1` declaration: **warning: implicit conversion of out of range value from 'float' to 'unsigned int' is undefined**. And the output on my Mac M1 is `6953232 0`.

Comment: You can convert a negative `int` to `unsigned`, it uses modular arithmetic. But conversion of negative `float` to `int` is undefined.

Comment: When you run up against Undefined Behaviour you usually lose the ability to predict the outcome. Sometimes you'll know enough about the target hardware and the compiler to be able to make use of undefined behaviour and accomplish amazing things, but most of the time you are just inviting suffering.

Comment: And you should use `%u` to print `unsigned`.

Comment: @Barmar: The difference is probably caused because one assignment is done at compiler time (literal assignment) while one is done at run time (assignment from variable probably register to memory). Since there is no definition of how it should work the two techniques may be different.

Comment: Side note: Never ignore compiler warnings. A compiler error means the code cannot be translated into a runnable program and you don't get anything you can run. A compiler warning means the code can be translated, but it probably doesn't do what you want. Since that unwanted result could take a long time to understand and correct, it's best to deal with the problem when the compiler tells you about it. In fact, you should turn more warnings on until the compiler has nothing left to tell you but trivial stuff that you know has no effect on your program and then turn the warnings down one level.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews of course involves truncation but differently because undefined behaviour - that was new for me.

Comment: @Barmar - That was the main point

Comment: clang++ and g++ both give a warning "warning: implicit conversion from 'float' to 'unsigned int' changes value from -123.123 to 0 [-Wliteral-conversion]" and set both u1 and u2 to 0 and print this for the %u printf.

Answer (score 12):

The behavior of converting a floating-point number less than or equal to −1 to an unsigned integer type is not defined by the C standard. C 2018 6.3.1.4 1 says:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

So, with `-123.123f`, the fractional part would be discarded, leaving −123. Then the integral part, −123, cannot be represented in an unsigned type, so the behavior is not defined.

In most operations with unsigned types, the mathematical result is wrapped modulo 2<sup>*w*</sup>, where *w* is the width (in bits) of the unsigned type. For example, `unsigned u = 0u - 123u;` or `unsigned u = -123;` would both wrap the number and produce a defined result (which would be 65,536 − 123 = 65,413 for a 16-bit `unsigned int` or 4,294,967,296 − 123 = 4,294,967,173 for a 32-bit `unsigned int`). For conversions from floating-point, the C standard does not say this wrapping occurs. The behavior is not defined.

What likely happens in your specific case is that, while compiling, the compiler uses its own code to produce some result for converting the floating-point number to `unsigned`, and this code produces zero, while, for the conversion from a variable, the compiler generates a processor instruction to perform the conversion, and that processor instruction produces the bits corresponding to −123 (two’s complement) or 4,294,967,173 (unsigned). Then, when those bits are sent to `printf` to be printed with `%d`, it prints the interpretation of those bits as an `int`, yielding output of “-123”. (This is further undefined behavior as `%d` should not be used with an `unsigned int`, and the C standard does not define what happens with this mismatch. However, interpreting the bits of the `unsigned int` as an `int` is common.)

Answer (score 2):

- `printf("%d %d\n", u1, u2);`
  This has undefined behavior because you're using `%d` instead of `%u`.
- `unsigned u1 = -123.123f;`
  This has undefined behavior because the truncated part of `-123.123` can't be represented in an `unsigned`. From the C23 draft:

  > 6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer
  >
  > 1. When a finite value of standard floating type is converted to an integer type other than `bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.<sup>65)</sup>
  >
  > <sup>65)The remaindering operation performed when a value of integer type is converted to unsigned type need not be
  > performed when a value of real floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus, the range of portable real floating values is
  > `(−1, Utype_MAX + 1)`.</sup>
- `unsigned u2 = f;`
  This has the same issue as mentioned in the bullet just above.

A possible conversion *with* defined behavior:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float f = -123.123f;
    unsigned u1 = (int)-123.123f;   // the int value will be -123
    unsigned u2 = (int)f;           // again, the int value will be -123
    printf("%u %u\n", u1, u2);      // prints two large values

    printf("%u\n", UINT_MAX - 122); // prints the same large value
}
```

The large values printed is because the `unsigned` variables will "wrap" around at zero:
`0u - 1 == UINT_MAX`, and `0u - 123` is the same as `UINT_MAX - 122`.